# Test data in JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm new in testing. So, I have a learning task.

This program calculate quadratic equation.

How can I check, for example, that c != 0 and D > 0 using JUnit?

I want to do it in the right way.

I tried to call input() from JUnit but the test became endless.

```
public class Main {
public static Scanner input;
public static double a, b, c;
public static double d;
public static double x1, x2;

public static void main(String args []) {
    input();
}

public static void input() {
    System.out.println("ax^2 + bx + c = 0");
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        System.out.print("a -> ");
        a = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("b -> ");
        b = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("c -> ");
        c = input.nextFloat();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Input number!\n");
        input();
    }

    if(a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0) {
        System.out.println("Not right\n");
        input();
        return;
    }

    calculate();
}

public static void calculate() {
    d = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);
    System.out.println("D = " + d);

    if(d < 0) {
        System.out.print("No answer");
    } else if(d == 0) {
        x1 = (-b) / (2 * a);
        System.out.println ("x = " + x1);
    } else {
        x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
        System.out.println("x1 =  " + x1);
        System.out.println("x2 = " + x2);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Show your test code...

Comment: First thing to do when testing: try to remove user input from mix. I suspect you shouldn't be using fields at all; instead, you can pass all your parameters directly to the `calculate` method. Testing `input` will be harder, given that you're using `System.in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is not testable in its current form. This is an alternative:

```
public class Parabola {
  // These are required in the constructor. Omitted for brevity
  private final double a;
  private final double b;
  private final double c;
  // Public API. Test this
  public double x1() { /*...*/ }
  public double x2() { /*...*/ }
}
```

Now writing tests is trivial:

```
@Test public void test1() {
  Parabola target = new Parabola(1, 2, 3);
  assertEquals(target.x1(), 44.23);
  assertEquals(target.x2(), 17.23);
}

@Test public void test2() {
  Parabola target = new Parabola(1, 0, 0);
  assertEquals(target.x1(), -1);
  assertEquals(target.x2(), 13.43);
}
```

And finally this is how a `main()` looks like:

```
public void main(String... args) throws Exception {
  Scanner console = ...;
  System.out.println("Type a:");
  Double a = Double.parseDouble(console.nextLine());
  // Same for b and c
  Parabola p = new Parabola(a, b, c);
  System.out.println("X axis intersected in "  + p.x1() + " and " + p.x2());
}
```

<sub>Bonus: When comparing `double`s in unit tests, you may want to use [this version of `assertEquals()`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.String,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) that accepts a `threshold` parameter because of how floating point arithmetic works and/or the decimal representation of binary numbers works</sub>

Comment: Thank you! But what if I want to test inputted data? That c != 0 and so on?
How can I do it? Thank you

Comment: You don't *test* input data. You test that the program computes the right `x1` and `x2` for the input (`a1`, `b1`, `c1`), then (`a2`, `b2`, `c2`) and so on. Write a test for each